# Writing a Debugger Love2d

Tags: lua, love2d

I wanted to write a debugger for my Love2d game, but I can't print() to the command line. When I try to use print() nothing appears in the command line.

Comment: The title of the question doesn't match the description. If the question is about buffered output, could you come up with a better title? If the question is about Love2d debugging, could you update the description?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might happen on some computers if you have console buffering turned on (by default).
You can call this at the beginning of your main.lua and see if it helps:

`io.stdout:setvbuf('no')`

Answer (score 2):

On the command line:

```
love folder-that-contains-main.lua --console
```

It's a special command line flag that will attach a console to your game window and display `print()` commands.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use "lovec ." instead of "love ." and it will make the print statements show in the console.

Comment: Works only for Windows